# API error 1 (datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): ApplicationError: 1 app "id1" cannot access app "id2"'s data

Tags: google-app-engine, go, blobstore, devserver

I am getting the following error on the AppEngine DevServer in Go:

> API error 1 (datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): ApplicationError: 1 app
>   "id1" cannot access app "id2"'s data

(where "id1" and "id2" are real identifiers used by two of my applications)

I have tried to empty the datastore using the --clear_datastore flag, and also specifying a new path to the datastore using --datastore_path. The latter did not seem to work, no data was stored at the new location. The former flag deleted the contents of the datastore, but whenever I try to upload a blob I get the error.

I am hoping there is something I can do to remedy this!

--EDIT: To clarify, I am not trying to move data across apps, I am merely trying to upload to the active app's blobstore. I am developing several apps at the same time (different companies), so the machine will have several datastores/blobstores. In Java this is not a problem, only in Go.

Also, this is only a problem on the DevServer, once I upload the app, everything works as it should.

Ex animo,
/Alexander.

Comment: Did you change the application id in app.yaml between your tests? Does it happen for all Go application or only this one?

Answer (score 0):

GAE Apps cannot direcly access each other's data. This is a fundamental restriction. DevAppServer is merely preventing you from doing something during development that would be forbidden to a deployed app.

You can move data between apps via url fetching.

Comment: I am not trying to do that.... I am just trying to upload to the running app's blobstore.

Comment: That's odd, then. What platform are you on? I'll try to reproduce the problem.